# Different output with normal environment & \newenvironment when citing

Tags: spacing, environments

I'm trying to simplify my work on thesis so I create an environment for repetitive tasks. All is ok, but citing!

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{romanian}
  {\quotedblbase}
  {\textquotedblright}
  {\guillemotleft}
  {\guillemotright}

\newenvironment{qt}[1]
      {\begin{quote}
      {\enquote{{#1}}}
      \end{quote}
      }

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
 title        = {Title},
 author       = {Author, An},
 year         = {2021},
 location     = {Location},
 publisher    = {Publisher}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

With \textbackslash newenvironment:
\qt
{Lorem ipsum dolor \enquote{sic} amet.}
\cite{key}
\endqt

With normal environment:

\begin{quote}
\enquote{Lorem ipsum dolor \enquote{sic} amet.}
\cite{key}
\end{quote}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few misunderstanding of how environments work.

First off, notwithstanding that `\newenvironment{foo}{...}{...}` defines `\foo` and `\endfoo` doesn't mean that one can use `\foo` and `\endfoo` in the document. To the contrary, they should ***not***.

Second problem. The command `\newenvironment` requires three mandatory arguments: the name of the environment, the code to be executed at the start and the code to be executed at the end. The parameter `#1` in the second mandatory argument does not refer to the environment contents.

Your code

```
\newenvironment{qt}[1]
      {\begin{quote}
      {\enquote{{#1}}}
      \end{quote}
      }
```

misses the final mandatory argument and, since it's followed by a blank line, the “end part” is taken to be `\par`. Let's see how the call

```
\qt
{Lorem ipsum dolor \enquote{sic} amet.}
\cite{key}
\endqt
```

is processed. The macro `\qt` is defined to have an argument, which is found to be the braced group following. Then the “begin part” is inserted and we find

```
\begin{quote}{\enquote{{Lorem ipsum dolor \enquote{sic} amet.}}}\end{quote}
\cite{key}
\endqt
```

Now the code is processed normally, finding `\cite{key}` outside `quote`. Finally `\par` results from `\endqt`.

How to fix?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{romanian}
  {\quotedblbase}
  {\textquotedblright}
  {\guillemotleft}
  {\guillemotright}

\newenvironment{qt}[1]
 {\begin{quote}\enquote{#1} \ignorespaces}
 {\end{quote}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
 title        = {Title},
 author       = {Author, An},
 year         = {2021},
 location     = {Location},
 publisher    = {Publisher}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

With \textbackslash newenvironment:
\begin{qt}{Lorem ipsum dolor \enquote{sic} amet.}
\cite{key}
\end{qt}

With normal environment:

\begin{quote}
\enquote{Lorem ipsum dolor \enquote{sic} amet.}
\cite{key}
\end{quote}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I initially wanted a command to have an environment inside because is easier for me to spot quotation in a large document, so I wrote this: `\newcommand{\qt}[1]{\begin{quote}\enquote{#1}\end{quote}}`. Since it didn't work (same problem - citing is jumping on new line) I tried the `newenvironment` command. I would prefer a command that have the environment inside. Also, since I'm new to LaTeX I'm not sure that this is the proper way.